# QTP Frame work design that can scale along with the AUT

Tags: qtp, ui-automation

Hi I am comfortable with the basics on QTP and DP.
I am planning to build a framework with QTP for our web portal application , which consists of a very rich GUI and lot of  features.
Please explain me the basic things I should care about while designing the frame work and
 the main components the frame work should be  having .

Answer (score 2):

When ever you are building a new framework there are lot many things that you would like to remember...

1. How are you goint to share the code between multiple people working. There are different ways this can be done, either through using a reusable actions or by using a function library.
2. How are you going to share the object repository. Even before that, you have to think whether you are going to build a shared object repository or do you want to do descriptive programming.
3. How are you going to give the data to the qtp scripts? Are you going to use excel or some other methodology?
4. Look at some existing frameworks, most of the cases you will have to go with a hybrid framework.

Don't write everything in the script, create modular scripts, that will help you to survive in the constantly changing world. you haven't mentioned what kind of GUI it is, see whether qtp supports that technology or not.

Except to do mistakes and allow good buffer time. If you don't have much time, don't think too much about automating it. You have to see how many cycles you will have to run the test cases that are to be automated. Building a fresh framework is very tough challenge, if you don't do it right, you will have to waste all the money you spend on it. Take some expert help.

Your question covers very broad range of topics. It cannot be answered in this small answer... check this link for better understanding... [A Tutorial on QTP Automation Frameworks](http://www.guru99.com/quick-test-professional-qtp-tutorial-34.html)

Check the answers for this question [Another Question that has useful information for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916580/how-do-you-write-your-qtp-tests)